# WCF method not receiving the parameters

Tags: c#, .net, wcf

I have a WCF method that is not receiving the request parameters. But if I use the WCFTest client (the one that comes with visual studio) the method receives the parameters.

If I capture the requests, they look very similar:

**If the request is this, it works:**

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
        <consultaValeCompra xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
            <dataMovto>1</dataMovto>
            <numSeqOperacao>2</numSeqOperacao>
            <numDocumento>3</numDocumento>
            <valorDocumento>4</valorDocumento>
            <tipo>5</tipo>
            <codPreVenda>6</codPreVenda>
        </consultaValeCompra>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

**If the request is this, I do not get the parameters:**

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <soapenv:Body>
        <consultaValeCompra xmlns="http://valeCompra/jaws">
            <dataMovto>121212</dataMovto>
            <numSeqOperacao>003719</numSeqOperacao>
            <numDocumento>000000000000005555466465454546</numDocumento>
            <valorDocumento>000046400</valorDocumento>
            <tipo>0</tipo>
            <codPreVenda>0000000000</codPreVenda>
        </consultaValeCompra>
    </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

The method signature is:

```
public Retorno consultaValeCompra(string dataMovto, string numSeqOperacao, string numDocumento, string valorDocumento, string tipo, string codPreVenda)
```

I can spot the differences, but I cannot understand why the first works and the second does not.

What can I do to make it work?

Thanks.

Comment: Which peach of code is causing the wrong rewuest? A generated propxy? javascript (jquery?)

Comment: The only - possibly - relevant difference I see is the namespace defined on the `consultaValeCompra` tag.

Comment: I think the XML namespace on the `<consultaValeCompra>` is the culprit; in the example that works, it's `http://tempuri.org/` - in the example that doesn't work, it's `http://valeCompra/jaws`. What is it in your service and/or operation contract of your service method??

Answer (score 3):

It seems that the XML namespace (`xmlns=` attribute) for `<consultaValeCompra>` are different :

```
<consultaValeCompra xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
```

versus

```
<consultaValeCompra xmlns="http://valeCompra/jaws">
```

**EDIT : corrected answer :**
You should check the `ServiceContract` attribute on your service class. Set it to the same namespace on both server and client side. For example :

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "http://valeCompra/jaws")]
public class MyService
{
     [...]
}
```

Or regenerate your service client.